# GWT Spring Jasper Reports

Tags: spring, gwt, jasper-reports

I have an application built in GWT and Spring. I am trying to generate Jasper Reports on the server side. However when I execute the functionality, it hangs/stops at `jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file_name);` and does not respond or throw an exception. This means that my RPC call that triggers the report generation function does not return a response either (so the application hangs). However when I run the function in a normal java application it generates a report without any problem. What could be the issue? I am using JasperReports version 5.6.0. My java function:

```
public StandardServerResponse printReport(List<Object> items) {
        StandardServerResponse response = new StandardServerResponse();
        String file_name = null;
        Map<String, Object> parameters;
        JasperDesign jasperDesign;
        JasperReport jasperReport;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint;

        try {
            for (Object  obj: items) {
                parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                parameters.put("id_in", obj.getId());
                file_name = "G:\\myreport.jrxml";

                jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file_name); //application stops here
                jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,  parameters, dataSource.getConnection());
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,  "G:\\report.pdf");
               }

            response.setSuccess(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.setSuccess(false);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Try using input stream to load the jrxml file instead of giving its direct path.

Comment: Thanks Lila, I tried that but when I passed the input stream it still stop at that particular line 'jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file_input_stream);'

Comment: Take your jasperDesign object outside the loop along with jasperReport. You do not require them in loop.

Comment: @Lila - I've done that too but still the app fails...for some reason no exception is being thrown either :-(

Comment: Where does your application stop, if you take objects outside the loop.

Comment: At the same line `jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file_name);`. I have taken out  `jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file_name);` and
`jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);` from the loop.

Comment: Try profiling your application to see if the heap gets full or something.

Comment: I still can't find anything wrong on profiling...no exception either

Comment: Use break points debug your complete code see where the bottle neck is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem after many long days of debugging :-).

I had these two jars in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
jasperreports-functions-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar
```

I removed them and the app worked. I still don't understand why they would cause a problem though.

I also changed my code to work with a `.jasper` extension and directly called `JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile(file_name, "S:\\output_report.pdf", parameters, connection);`

Thanks a lot **Darshan Lila** for trying, I really appreciate. Hope this helps someone.